# No options-button shown with Android 2.2 build?

Tags: android, android-layout

until now I compiled my app with SDK for Android 2.1. There the options/preferences button appeared automatically, I only had to bring it alive by providing methods onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onMenuItemSelected().

Now i switched over to SDK for 2.2 and my whole layout is...hm...damaged. Most obvious problem: the options-button is gone.

So what do I have to do to re-enable it for 2.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There the options/preferences button appeared automatically

There has never been an "options/preferences button" in Android that "appeared automatically". I am going to guess that you mean the legacy menu affordance in the system bar/navigation bar on Android 3.0 devices, for apps with `android:minSdkVersion` set too low.

> So what do I have to do to re-enable it for 2.2?

The legacy menu affordance has nothing to do with your build target. It has everything to do with your `android:minSdkVersion`. More importantly, your objective should be to get rid of this affordance, as it is a sign to users that your app is out of date.

If you are using `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, you should be using the action bar, in which case your former menu items will either appear in the action bar directly as toolbar-style buttons, or in the action bar's overflow menu ("..." button), or via a popup menu that appears when the user presses their device's MENU button.

If you do not want the action bar, then do not use `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Instead, create your own menu structure using your own widgets as part of your own activity UI.

You can read more about [the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and [the vanishing menu affordance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks!Sounds like a step backward for me - just to have a preferences menu I have to waste some space for a full action bar now. Or is there a possibility to place such a action-menu right beside home and back-button?

Comment: @Elmi: "just to have a preferences menu I have to waste some space for a full action bar now" -- or, just put a `Button` somewhere. " Or is there a possibility to place such a action-menu right beside home and back-button?" -- no, other than the legacy menu affordance discussed in my answer (which, again, makes your app look like you aren't maintaining it).